# Undefined method `to_i' for #<Reason:0x56f5848>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently pretty stumped on this one. I recently had to update my rails application and now am seeing this error popup whenever I try to save an object that also tries to save a Visitor object. Here is the code that is failing:

```
if @sale.shift_id.nil?
            @sale.update_attribute(:shift_id,session[:shift_id])
            @title = "New Sale"
            @sale = Sale.new
            @products = Product.order("name")
            @shifts = Shift.order("starttime")

#this line below is line 51, which the output says is the failing line.
            Visitor.new(:gender => 'Other', :shift_id => session[:current_shift_id], :reason_id => Reason.find_by_name("Products")).save

            redirect_to(newsale_path, :notice => 'successfully added the sale')
        else
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `to_i' for #<Reason:0x56f5848>
Rails.root: 

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:51:in `new'
app/controllers/sales_controller.rb:51:in `create'
```

At first I thought it might be the Reason.find_by_name, so I replaced that with a valid integer value and it still failed. The only other bit of code that I can see that might fail is the routes.rb, which has an entry under:

```
match 'newsale', :to => 'sales#newsale'
```

Lastly, the output to the webrick is confusing because it actually shows the sql calls saving the @sale object, and then I get the following lines:

```
SELECT "reasons".* FROM "reasons" WHERE "reasons"."name" = 'Products' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 104ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:reason_id => Reason.find_by_name("Products")` here Rails is trying to cast the found `Reason` instance to an integer value to set as the `:reason_id` attribute on `Visitor` by calling `.to_i` on it *(which doesn't exist)*.

You need to tell Rails where the id is by changing

```
Reason.find_by_name("Products")
```

to

```
Reason.find_by_name("Products").id
```

You can alternatively define a `to_i` method on `Reason` and leave your action as-is.

```
alias_method :to_i, :id
```

Comment: No dice. Note that above I stated that I replaced the find_by_name call with an integer value and it still failed with the same error.

Comment: I doubt the error is the same since your original code is absolutely problematic.

Comment: I'm not even sure how it worked before. It looks like I was having a git error that wasn't pushing up the fixed files, so now it's fixed with the id there. I'm just confused why it worked before and not now...